# I can populate ServiceType but can't get the right values for ServiceName(dependent drop down list)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I have the right ServiceName dropdown values based on ServiceType dropdown selected values.

```js
$scope.ServiceTypeAndName = [    
    { 
      "id":0,
      "type":"",
      "list":""
    },
     { 
      "id":1,
      "type":"In-Person",
      "list":["ADL Functional Assessment", "Community Functional Assessment", "Future Care Cost Analysis"]
    },
     { 
      "id":2,
      "type":"Paper Review",
      "list":["OT - In Home Assessment - ABI", "OT - In Home Assessment Attendant Care with Form 1", "OT - Occupational Therapy Assessment"]
          
    },
     { 
      "id":3,
      "type":"Administration",
      "list":["Situational Assessment", "Situational Assessment (OT) - Day 1", "Situational Assessment (OT) - Day 2", "Construction Cost Consulting"]
    }  
];


$scope.selectedLine = [{"Event_ID": "100", "Service_Type": "In-Person", "Service_Name": "Community Functional Assessment"}, {"Event_ID": "101", "Service_Type": "Paper Review", "Service_Name": "OT - Occupational Therapy Assessment"},{"Event_ID": "102", "Service_Type": "In-Person", "Service_Name": "Future Care Cost Analysis"}];
```

```html
<select ng-model="selectedLine.Service_Type" name="ServiceType" class="form-control">
   <option ng-repeat="temp in ServiceTypeAndName" value="{{temp.type}}">{{temp.type}}</option>
</select>
          
<select ng-model="selectedLine.Service_Name" name="ServiceName" ng-required="selectedLine.Service_Type!=''" class="form-control"> 
  
</select>
```

for example, if I load the first object then the value  "In-Person" should be selected in the first dropdown and the value "Community Functional Assessment" should be selected in the second dropdown along with the  corresponding list values and if I change first dropdown then the corresponding list values should be populated in the second dropdown.

Comment: You might want to clarify your last paragraph. It's hard to understand what you end goal is. Also, your line `ng-repeat="temp in selectedLine.ServiceNameList"` referes to a property `ServiceNameList` that does not exist on your `selectedLine`. In this case `selectedLine` is an array.

Comment: I have updated the paragraph and my second select HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is structured in a way that does not make this the easiest, but it still isn't the worst:

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/g4B27vMtf35vOQxnAgfu?p=preview)

Basically you need to find out which object in the `ServiceTypeAndName` array you are matching on. This requires a filter:

```
$scope.selectedLineChanged = function () {                  
   $scope.SelectedServiceTypeAndName = $filter('filter')($scope.ServiceTypeAndName, $scope.selectedLine.Service_Type)[0];           
};
```

Here's the thing: I don't know how you plan on loading your selected items, the ones you store in the `selectedLines` array. I load the items via a select box in that plnkr.

When the top box is changed, it matches the remaining two.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. Would you suggest any changes in my structure to make it easier?

Comment: @KarimAli Well I wasn't sure if you were in control of your data structures, so I was working within those confines. After reviewing it, as long as you are ok with my introduction of the object that tracks the match in the `ServiceTypeAndName`, then your data structures seem good.